# Split a string with unescaped delimiter only

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I want to split a string with `,` as delimiter.  My problem is that in some cases the input may contains commas. Changing the delimiter is not an option. I want users to be able to escape comma with `\`, and so I want to split only on `,` **but not** on `\,` like so:

```
str="1,10,100,1\,000,10\,000,100\,000"
while [[ ${#str} -gt 0 ]]; do
    #Get index of delimiter
    index=$(echo "$str" | grep -boP '(?<!\\),' | head -c 1)

    #If index is empty, there is nothing to do
    if [[ -z "$index" ]]; then
        echo "$str"
        break
    fi

    #Get the next string we're looking for
    echo "$str" | cut -c1-$index
    #Cut the original string
    str=$(echo "$str" | cut -c$(($index+2))-${#str})
done
```

This is currently printing:

```
1
10
100
1\,000
10\,000
100\,000
```

But I want it to print:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
```

I can now use `sed` to replace `\,` with `,` but this entire solution seems quite bulky for relatively simple problem. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have the power to manipulate your data before trying to split it, why not just use a character that you know won't be in there. # for example. Then you can just split by comma and replace all # with , afterwards?

Comment: @Remuze yes, that is also an option, but in doing that I will be adding a restricted character, which is what `,` is supposed to be. So if someone wants to use `#` one day, I will sit with a similar problem.

Comment: You'll need to be able to escape your backslashes if necessary (if one of your items ends in `\`, you'll want to write it as `\\`).  This can get quite unmanageable in pure shell...

Comment: The way the rest of the world does this is to enclose fields that contain the separator in double quotes, like so `1,10,100,"1,000","10,000","100,000"`. I think it would be wise of you to adopt the same standard, which would avail you of library software that will handle your data for you

Comment: @Borodin I'm starting to think this would be the best. Any suggestions as where to start?

Comment: @Ian2thedv: That depends on what information you have to *start with*. I'm a Perl programmer and would recommend that you install [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) which will do all the formatting for you. Others will be able to help you better if you prefer a different language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ str="1,10,100,1\,000,10\,000,100\,000"
$ sed 's/\([^\]\),/\1\n/g' <<< $str
1
10
100
1\,000
10\,000
100\,000
```

With `bash` one-liner:

```
$ sed 's/\([^\]\),/\1\n/g' <<< $str | while read -r line; do echo "-> $line"; done
-> 1
-> 10
-> 100
-> 1\,000
-> 10\,000
-> 100\,000
```

As per comment by @fedorqui, by this way you can avoid opening a sub-shell.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "-> $line"; done < <(sed 's/\([^\]\),/\1\n/g' <<< "$str")
```

Comment: @fedorqui Loosing the character is what I wanted in this case, thanks sat, great solution!

Comment: @lan2thedv, I was losing one character from your original value. That's now fixed.

Comment: Note you can also say `while IFS= read -r; do ... done < <(sed '...' <<< "$str")` so that you do not open a sub-shell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way:

```
str="1,10,100,1\,000,10\,000,100\,000"
echo "$str" |sed -n 's/\([0-9]\+\(\\,[0-9]*\)*\),\+/\1\n/gp'
1
10
100
1\,000
10\,000
100\,000
```

With `tr` you can just remove those backslashes:

```
str="1,10,100,1\,000,10\,000,100\,000"
echo "$str" |sed -n 's/\([0-9]\+\(\\,[0-9]*\)*\),\+/\1\n/gp' |tr -d '\\'
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu `awk` you can use `FPAT` to use complex regex to parse each field separately:

```
str="1,10,100,1\,000,10\,000,100\,000"

awk -v FPAT='[^,\\\\]*(\\\\.[^,\\\\]*)*|[^,]*' '{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d: <%s>\n", i, $i}' <<< "$str"

1: <1>
2: <10>
3: <100>
4: <1\,000>
5: <10\,000>
6: <100\,000>
```